# Self-answering without peer-review: benefit or harmful

Tags: discussion

I posted a question and after some subsequent time, i added my own answer.
There was no participation of any other parties.

I added my own solution to the problem in question, solely for the benefit of people facing similar questions. But as there was no review of any kind, I'm not sure, if posting my own answer is leading people astray here or if it has some benefit to it. Would it have been more constructive keeping it as was before or is deleting the post entirely a better way to proceed?

For the sake of completeness, the link of the referred post is:
[Destructive interference on the Autocorrelation of the time signal of periodic CPFSK-signals.](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/42815/destructive-interference-on-the-autocorrelation-of-the-time-signal-of-periodic-c)

Comment: i've done that a couple of times.  where i post a question that i **intend** to answer myself.  sometimes i get interest from other people and sometimes i do not.

Comment: [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is yes - you can and you should answer your own questions. Please read more about it in the [FAQ](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).
However, I do not understand what do you mean by "there was no review of any kind"?

Comment: People might take my answer at face value and assume it to be correct, when it needn't be.

Comment: Same could happen with other people answering your question. I'd say that your answer is correct until proven otherwise.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help.

Comment: I agree with this. Definitely put an answer in if it solved your problem. Even if it's "rough and ready" it's better than not putting the information out there.

Comment: I think you should answer your questions if you find the solution. However there are some people who like to mark this as negative unfortunately.